# When do insects normally hatch from insect houses?

Tags: bugs, bees

I have a bug house and it looks as if several insects have laid in the house over the spring/summer.
All of the bamboo seems to be clogged up and has been for a couple of months.

Are there still insects in there to hatch?

Would insects dig this out next year to lay again?

[image: Insect House]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely these are solitary bees.

> You might notice bees buzzing around your house and on wet days during the flying season check inside the holes and might see them sheltering from the rain.
>
> The only certain sign of nesting is seeing the ends of the tubes capped with either mud, leaves or fine hairs. The type of capping indicates the type of bee and it’s possible you might have more than more one type at the same time.

They will stay in the tubes for a few months, and come out in the spring. From the look of your photo there's a lot of mud on the end of the tubes and one clearly stands out in green for leaves. So this could then be:

> Red mason bee, Osmia bicornis (Osmia rufa) – red/gingery hair, females have small horns on their heads = use mud to cap tubes
>
> Leaf cutter bee, Megachile willughbiella – broad head, large mandibles for cutting leaves and an upturned abdomen = use leaves (May–September)

The tubes should clear out in the spring and the new bees will go off to find new mates/homes. The tubes should be replaced, or cleaned, once the bees have gone, to prevent spread of disease.

[Take a crash course in solitary bees](https://www.growwilduk.com/wildflowers/bees-pollinators/take-crash-course-solitary-bees)

Answer (score 3):

The Bug House in the question stayed as it was until March and then a couple of holes started to appear.

The first image is from the 16th March. One or two holes starting to appear.
[image: 16March]

Very little happened for a few weeks. Then over the Easter weekend we had the first warm weather. Then a lot more holes started to appear.

The second image is from 13th April. The Monday after the warm Easter weekend. This shows a lot more holes.
[image: 13April]

Since more holes started to appear bees have been flying around by the bug house and I think some appear to be filled in again.